# W/System.err: Unexpected character () at position 0

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

> I am trying to parse json response from this link:
>   https://www.move2mart.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=watches
>   and this is what i am getting no matter what i do.
>   W/System.err: Unexpected character () at position 0.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String url="https://www.move2mart.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=mens-fashion";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            textView.setText(response);
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

                Log.d("Inside","1");
            try {
                Log.d("Inside","2");

                org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = (org.json.JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(response);



                try {
                    //org.json.JSONArray jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(jsonArray.getString(0))));
                    String t1=jsonObject2.getString("id");
                    Log.d("Inside3",t1);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

> Log Response: 08-15 08:40:46.266
>   18845-18845/com.example.princ.learningjsonvolly D/Inside: 1
>
> 08-15 08:40:46.266 18845-18845/com.example.princ.learningjsonvolly
>   D/Inside: 2
>
> 08-15 08:40:46.267 18845-18845/com.example.princ.learningjsonvolly
>   W/System.err: Unexpected character () at position 0.
>
> 08-15 08:40:46.268 18845-18845/com.example.princ.learningjsonvolly
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
>
> 08-15 08:40:46.268 18845-18845/com.example.princ.learningjsonvolly
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)

Comment: 22 Mins and no response :'(

Comment: I was unable to read the content of https://www.move2mart.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=watches. Can you please let me know the charset of this page?

Comment: From the exception, I think the json file is malformed

Comment: Please use this for better understanding: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: The json is generated by this api : http://v2.wp-api.org/

Comment: I think you wrongly used WP-API, the correct call should be https://www.move2mart.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/524 instead of https://www.move2mart.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=watches

Comment: let me check this.

Comment: the response is giving something like ��[�$���B��j>x�1�(��v���A�+�z�p���Q�n[���_����L��F�7����x<�Q���O��9�& �ü_O.IK�.�~݇�,�
��[����Ě'܀�P}��#�v�'P��G2�хU�Cn�����\��I)Hϵ��8���SR���U�'����D���lm�����-_�x��7;!�ǋ��qva�a�T�}�F��Rk&�^M�����_�8lu�_
��5����sN�:�žqg����+Ήb>�,���+�� ���Ǔ�0.���� �a��l���e��pUȑ�\N �����FKa���&dX+���76E�X�!�B3@"��K��x�B�FQVdT�[�+�-��mj��{j�$\�Ͳ�ͨ�<��偑[a0L���#7�~P*��M��9�� O����L��|�?

Comment: Ok, fixed the junk issue but still getting the same error, undefined character () at position 0.

Comment: Check the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your response in gzip encoding, so let make GzipRequest:

```
public class GZipRequest extends StringRequest {

    public GZipRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
    }

    public GZipRequest(String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(url, listener, errorListener);
    }

    // parse the gzip response using a GZIPInputStream
    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String output = ""; // note: better to use StringBuilder

        try {
            final GZIPInputStream gStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.data));
            final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gStream);
            final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String read;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                output += read;
            }
            reader.close();
            in.close();
            gStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError());
        }
        return Response.success(output, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
}
```

And modify a little bit in your code:

```
GZipRequest stringRequest = new GZipRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        textView.setText(response);

        try {
            org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(response);

            String t1 = jsonObject.getString("id");

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: by doing this i am getting:  W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value ��������������o�8?��՞n���O�L���N of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I think your page has response in gzip. Let check updated answer.

Comment: Check it by show the t1 variable by toast in the above sample code